# Can I recover cut and pasted data in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, data-recovery

I cut and pasted a big file from my file system to an external disk and then I realized the transferred file was corrupted. It seems that the transferring of the data didn't end but the operating system told me otherwise.
Is there an easy way to recover the data?
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Do you mean in Nautilus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so. The only was I could prevent data-loss on Ubuntu was: safely remove THEN sudo sync and THEN remove the pendrive.